# What is the most important feature of caches in scientific computing?

Tags: parallel-processing, cpu-architecture, hpc, cpu-cache

I have started recently learning parallel programming techniques and what to give attention to when trying to create efficient programs. For example knowing specific details about the caches of your processor is essential if you want to write efficient programs.

I want to know what is the most important (if one is more important than the other) feature of a cache between the block size and the number of sets e.g. 4-way or 8-way associative.

Comment: If you have other questions, then you should post new questions, not modify existing ones.

Comment: I received bad criticizing because my question was not clear.. i changed it to be more specific

Comment: That's OK, but your edit completely changed the question (which I think would be better on https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: OK then thank you, I will ask there (stackexchange) for this type of questions. Is there a way to delete this question from here? I cannot ask other questions because of this now..

Comment: What do you mean? You can't click on the "Ask Question" button? I think you still ask questions here or on any other forum.

Comment: It says that I am in danger of getting blocked because my question was downvoted. In any way, thanks a lot!

Comment: I have no problem with this post and I upvoted. For future posts, make sure that your question is clear and relevant. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.

Comment: @AndreasHadjigeorgiou: If you're not *actually* question-banned, then that's just a warning to tell you that could happen if you ask more poorly-received questions.  This one is not great, and borderline too broad (because there are many different kinds of HPC workloads, and "more important" is hard to define).  I posted a simplistic answer instead of writing the same thing as a comment, because it look like an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associativity matters more than line size.  Many accesses in HPC are sequential, so smaller line size is mostly just a waste of tag overhead.

Having more smaller sets (because of a smaller line size) might help for a histogram problem, which is one of the major things that can't easily be optimized to sequential accesses.

Of course, latency and bandwidth are usually even more important than 4 vs. 8-way.